# Не работает Xdebug в Netbeans

Tags: php

Часа 3 потратил, чтоб он заработал и никак.

Php 5.4

В-общем скачал PHP 5.4 VC9 TS (32 bit), кинул в /ext, в php.ini добавил:

> `zend_extension = "C:\PHP\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
> [XDebug]
> ; данные для подключения к удаленному отладчику
> xdebug.remote_host=localhost
> xdebug.remote_port=9900
> xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
> xdebug.remote_mode=req
> ; стартовать отладку каждый раз при http-запросе к серверу
> xdebug.remote_autostart=1
> ; ключ, чтобы каждый раз при старте сессии отладки, дебагер подключался именно к NetBeans и принимал от нее управляющие команды
> xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug`

В phpinfo видно xdebug. В netbeans все настройки облазил. Все перепробовал. Не хочет.

Что не так может быть?

Comment: Дополню, возьмите лучше `php 7.*`. `5.4`, уже старо, как мамонт.

Answer (score 0):

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=\usr\local\php5\ext\php_xdebug-2.1.0-5.3-vc6.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
```

Если php 5.2 - то надо использовать zend_extension_ts вместо zend_extension
В настройках нетбинса указать пусь к php, указать порт отладчика такой же как в php.ini и идентификатор сеанса,к примеру у меня он равен - netbeans-xdebug, указать "Остановиться в первой строке".
Все эти настройки выполнять в меню Сервис/параметры/PHP.

Если вы говорите что в phpinfo xdebug есть, то проблема скорее всего только в IDE. Попробуйте либо мой конфиг либо в своем удалите строки:

```
xdebug.remote_mode=req ; стартовать отладку каждый раз при http-запросе к серверу xdebug.remote_autostart=1 ; ключ, чтобы каждый раз при старте сессии отладки, дебагер подключался именно к NetBeans и принимал от нее управляющие команды xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug
```

Comment: php 5.4.0
насколько я понимаю zend_extension[_ts] зависит от того, включен ли параметр Thread Safety. У меня аnable, поэтому. Я попробовал через _ts. Не помогло...

Answer (score 0):

В php.ini автора вопороса пропущен:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
```

Для php 5.4 нужно указывать zend_extention вне зависимости от TS, not TS =>
[пруф](http://xdebug.org/docs/install) :

> From PHP 5.3 onwards, you always need to use the zend_extension PHP.ini setting name, and not zend_extension_ts, nor zend_extension_debug.

У меня получилось запустить отладку со встроенным сервером php 5.4

```
php.exe -S localhost:3000
```

Но Netbeans 7.1, 7.2 останавливается на точке остановки (breakpoint) только один раз, после чего необходимо перезапускать Netbeans :(.

Конфигурация: php 5.4.4 x86 VC9,  Xdebug v2.2.0, Windows 7 x64

Comment: в Eclipse PDT debug работает стабильнее, но на крупных проектах (например, Vanilla Forum v2 ) встроенный сервер падает.

Answer (score 0):

Для отладки на удаленном сервере измените `.remote_host=localhost` на адрес, по которому сидит `Netbeans`.
Т.о. `Netbeans` является сервером на порту 9000, а расширения `xdebug` на веб-сервере - клиентом
`Netbeans` начинает ждать подключения на 9000 сразу после запуска отладки
Не забудьте проверить открытость порта на межсетевом экране

Comment: У var_dump как и print_r масса минусов:
-необходимость чистки кода после них
-сложность анализа ООП-кода с кучей связанных переменных

Отладка выводит на совсем другой уровень. Конечно, если проект простой или нет поддержки в IDE использования отладки - тогда и я использую :)

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте, что у вас установлен php-cgi. Xdebug без него работать не хочет. Netbeans ничего о нем не говорит, а вот Phpstorm поругался бы.

Answer (score -1):

У меня был закрыт порт 9000.
Открыл все заработало